# How to validate an html form and interact with php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have this html form that interacts with a `MySQL` database created in `XAMPP`. I'd like to validate it in such a way that once controlled the first two boxes(Name and Email areas) are filled it sends the message to the database using a php script I wrote.
I have written the javascript code to validate the form, but it works even if the first two fields are not filled, so it's wrong in some way. 
Here are the files(html, javascript and php):

html form

```
<html>

<header>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/validateForm.js"></script>

    <?php include("connectivity.php"); ?>
</header>

<body>

<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="connectivity.php">
        <div class="form_settings">
            <p><span>Name and Surname</span>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
            </p>
            <p><span>Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </p>
            <p><span>Message</span>
                <textarea rows="8" cols="50" name="messaggio" id="messaggio"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span>
                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="invia" value="Invia" onclick="checkForm()" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript file to validate(it is wrong in some way)

```
function exists(input) {
    atLeastOneChar = false;
    if (input) {
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) != " ") {
                atLeastOneChar = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return atLeastOneChar;
}

function checkForm() {
    mes = "";
    if (!exists(document.contactForm.nome.value))
        mes = mes + "Missing name\n";
    if (!exists(document.contactForm.email.value))
        mes = mes + "Missing email\n";
    if (mes != "")
        alert(mes);
    if (mes == "") {
        alert("Ok, correct!\nThe form should now be sent to " +
            "the server!");

    }
}
```

php file to interact with database

```
<?php


    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myprojectdb;charset=utf8', 
                  'root', 
                  '',
                  array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


?>
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['nome'])) {

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $messaggio =  $_POST['messaggio'];



    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `contatti` (contattoNome,contattoEmail,messaggio)
    VALUES (:nome, :email, :messaggio)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':messaggio', $messaggio);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'email inviata correttamente';

}

?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get your own validation to work. It's much easier using a jQuery Validation plugin like:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Or I prefer:

http://parsleyjs.org/

They are pretty straight forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is actually returning the correct result?

```
!exists(document.contactForm.nome.value)
```

Because it seems to me that a "value" will exist whether it's populated with something or not.
Have you tried:

```
docuemnt.getElementById("nome").value != '';
```

Also, your button is of type "submit".  It's going to submit whatever happens regardless of the message.  You should change that to "button".

EDIT:  added code for button type:

```
<input class="submit" type="button" name="invia" value="Invia" onclick="checkForm()" />
```

Then, in your code:

```
if (mes == "") {
        alert("Ok, correct!\nThe form should now be sent to " +
            "the server!");
        document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. With your code, the message is sent even if I don't fill any area of the form. Any idea?

Comment: yes. Probably I'll making some mistakes in replacing some the code you gave me. Could you post the whole javascript code?

Comment: What I have there IS the relevant code.  But I'll edit to add what the button should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions should return false if validation fails and you should call js validation function in onsubmit event in form.  Replace these two lines.

1)javascript file to validate
if (mes != ""){
        alert(mes);
return false // add this line in js file
}

Comment: 2) in HTML file.
<form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post"action="connectivity.php" onsubmit=" return checkForm()"> // call checkform in on submit..